# Toobar drops shadow on TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

everybody! I have a fragment in FrameLayout container within activity, which has Navigation Drawer. Fragment has TabLayout. And the problem is, as you can see, that 
activity's toolbar drops shadow on fragment's TabLayout. I dont want to place TabLayout in activity's AppBar layout because I won't have access to it from fragment and, moreover, I don't need that TabLayout anywhere else.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mainNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

And this is `app_bar_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/loginToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is `fragment_by_day_schedule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/byDayTabLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabBackground="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/byDayViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also want the Toolbar to hide when I scroll up list in fragment within ViewPager

Do you have any ideas how can I achive that?

Comment: What makes you think you won't have access to the tablayout from the fragment if you put it inside the toolbar?

Honestly, i think its a much better and far more widely understood pattern to have the tabs inside the toolbar. You can also achieve the effect of hiding the toolbar as you move up the viewpager.

Comment: Check my answer again. I updated for your second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this. Works on my projects.

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(mAppBarLayout, 0);
```

And your second question how to hide your toolbar?
Change your parent layout linearlayout to layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/loginToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After this you have to tell android when toolbar should be hide. You should tell which view can be scroll. You have add this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to in your ViewPager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/byDayTabLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabBackground="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/byDayViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Never knew about ViewCompat.setElevation()

Answer (score 2):

The AppBarLayout in support library v24.0.0 uses `StateListAnimator`. Setting `appBayLayout.setElevation(0)` will have no effect if you use in this new version.

Instead try setting elevation to 0 in the `StateListAnimator` as follows for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21`:

```
StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = new StateListAnimator();
stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "elevation", 0));
appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);
```

Answer (score 2):

From Support Library v24.0.0 `AppBarLayout` uses `StateListAnimator` for set elevation. For get the same behaviour as pre-24.0.0 just set animator as null and call `setElevation()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    appbarLayout.setStateListAnimator(null);
}

ViewCompat.setElevation(appbarLayout, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to ensure everything has the same elevation.

Comment: I don't want to use `elevation` because it doesn't work on pre-lollipop

Comment: I'm not sure this is a want to / dont want to scenario... Shadows are drawn from elevation. If you dont want shadows, you should specify an elevation of 0. Though, this will flatten your design and contradict the Material Design language pattern of using Surfaces.

Comment: Just tried that on pre-lollipop and that works, but on API 21+ doesn't work. No effect(